# Why the hessian needs to be positive definite to distinguish extrema?

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier, hessian-matrix

I have a test in 2 days and I can't figure out why I need the hessian to be positive definite to distinguish extrema. In other words, why do we need the condition $$w^{T} \cdot \nabla_{x}^{2}L(a,\lambda) \cdot w > 0$$

Comment: for $C^2$ functions: positive definite implies local convexity. covexity implies semi-positive definite

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Write the Taylor expansion up to second derivative .

Comment: Yeah I have done that ane we find that if we have positive defined we have f (a+h)>f (a) for all h then a is a minimum but that's just it ? Is there an intuitive way to think about it ?

Comment: Intuitively it says function about the point curves up, like $x^2$ about zero ! @Haatox